# SQL connection problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

We have a helper class that we use to call stored procs on SQL Server. The helper function looks like this:

```
using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            // Create database command object
            sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

            // Set command text AND command type
            sqlCmd.CommandText = procedureName;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Set command parameters
            if (paramCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (DatabaseParameter dbParam in paramCollection)
                {
                    SqlParameter sqlParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(dbParam.ParameterName, dbParam.ParameterType);
                    sqlParam.Direction = dbParam.ParameterDirection;
                    sqlParam.Value = dbParam.ParameterValue;
                    if (dbParam.ParameterSize != -1)
                        sqlParam.Size = dbParam.ParameterSize;
                    if (dbParam.ParamPrecision != -1)
                        sqlParam.Precision = (byte)dbParam.ParamPrecision;
                    if (dbParam.ParamScale != -1)
                        sqlParam.Scale = (byte)dbParam.ParamScale;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                sqlCon.Open();
            }

            // Prepare command
            sqlCmd.Prepare();

            // Execute the statement
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (sqlCmd.Parameters.Contains("@Result"))
                return sqlCmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value;
            else
                return "Completed";
        }
```

So we are making sure connections are closed properly. 
The app is a multi threaded service and all the threads calls this method quite regularly. We do lock (thisobject) {} sections around the code that calls the above helper method to prevent the threads from stealing each others connections.

The connection.Open is inside a try catch with the ClearAllpools to clear broken connections.

However, we intermittently through the day get the following list of errors at random intervals.

> The connection's current state is connecting.

or

> The connection's current state is open.

The errors happen about once in every several thousand times the code is called, so it's quite hard to troubleshoot. Has anybody seen anything similar or ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: your try-catch block looks fishy - why would you clear the connection pool in the first place, and after that *expect* that the connection will now be able to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across these types of errors when dealing with a multi-threaded app, even when using a `lock`. After endless hours of debugging, I never found the problem and ended up trying to re-connect several times before giving up. To date, I haven't seen the error arise again.

```
int retries = 5;
while( true )
{
    try
    {
        DbCommand cmd = GetCommand( sql );
        using( DbConnection conn = cmd.Connection )
        {
            conn.Open();
            // do stuff
            break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        if( retries-- <= 0 )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say for certain why the connection is failing.  But what's *wrong* is your `catch` block.  You're ignoring the actual error and replacing it with an unhelpful one (the one(s) you're seeing).

*Never* ignore exceptions.  They're thrown for a reason and tend to contain useful information about an unexpected error encountered by the system.  You're having trouble figuring out the problem because you're throwing away that useful information without ever looking at it.

The errors you're seeing are coming out of the code in your `catch` block.  This code is essentially trying to do the exact thing that just failed, but in a slightly different way.  You need to log your error so you can find out why it's failing and reaching the `catch` block in the first place.

A good rule of thumb for `try/catch` blocks is that you should only catch the exception if you're prepared to *handle* the exception.  Here you aren't handling it at all, so unless you do so you should just remove the `try/catch` entirely.  Let the exception bubble up to somewhere that it can be handled.  Alternatively, replace the code in the `catch` block with some error logging and exit the code block in a useful and meaningful way (return an error to the calling code block, throw a custom exception with the caught exception inside of it, etc.).

Comment: You are right, that is not the most useful try catch block ever, and I do also hate it when people use try catch for no good reason. The code above is actually part of a bigger try catch with proper logging and handling, but the little try catch around the connection open is a result of desperate measures. :)

Answer (score 0):

All else aside, have you tried proceeding conditionally, based on the connection's [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state.aspx)?

```
using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: We have tried that before but still had the same errors. From other questions on Stack Overflow I gathered that connections in the pool that can disconnected do not get their state changed. So even though the connection state = Open it is actually a broken connection. That is partly why we open the connection in the try catch with the ClearAllPools call.